# Static Methods in Python

Tags: python, static-methods

I am trying to simulate the rolling of a die and have used this code

```
class dicesimulator:
    def __init__(self, list = [0,0,0,0,0,0]):
        self.list = list

    @staticmethod
    def diceroller():
        outcome = random.randit(0,5)
        print outcome + 1


mydice = dicesimulator()
print mydice.diceroller
```

However when I run the code it returns  rather then a number. Why is this happening. Also as far as I am aware I should also be able to call the class itself on a static method ie dicesimulator.diceroller. However, it also returns

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple of issues. Firstly, there's not really a terribly good reason to use static methods. It's essentially no different than just making a function. Secondly, you aren't actually returning the number from within your diceroller() method. Thirdly, you aren't actually calling diceroller because you forgot to put parens so instead you're just printing the function directly (the string representation of it).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parens.

```
mydice.diceroller()
```

Comment: Thanks! Had tried that but it returned a error turned out that in the above code I wrote randit rather then randint!

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found the indentation repair.
(1) You asked for the diceroller object, rather than calling the method.
(2) There is no "randit".  Try "randint".

```
import random

class dicesimulator:
    def __init__(self, list = [0,0,0,0,0,0]):
        self.list = list
```

This yields output

```
6
None
```

Note that you have not returned anything from the function diceroller.  You also haven't used dicesimulator.list for anything yet.

Consider searching the internet for implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to complicate things by unnecessarily using classes and static methods.

```
from random import randint
print(randint(1,6))
```